# Neovim, how to jump back to a terminal

Tags: neovim

`help terminal-input` said

```
To use `ALT+{h,j,k,l}` to navigate windows from any mode: >
    :tnoremap <A-h> <C-\><C-N><C-w>h
    :tnoremap <A-j> <C-\><C-N><C-w>j
    :tnoremap <A-k> <C-\><C-N><C-w>k
    :tnoremap <A-l> <C-\><C-N><C-w>l
    :inoremap <A-h> <C-\><C-N><C-w>h
    :inoremap <A-j> <C-\><C-N><C-w>j
    :inoremap <A-k> <C-\><C-N><C-w>k
    :inoremap <A-l> <C-\><C-N><C-w>l
    :nnoremap <A-h> <C-w>h
    :nnoremap <A-j> <C-w>j
    :nnoremap <A-k> <C-w>k
    :nnoremap <A-l> <C-w>l
```

.
Thus I add these shortcut maps into my init file. And when a terminal is open, i type <A-j>, the cursor jumped from the terminal into the normal interface (The terminal interface does not close.). i want jump back to the terminal interface. However, all the shortcuts do not work. They only jump across windows.

Comment: Not sure if it is the same terminal I used before, but when you jump back to a terminal you need to use insert mode (just press `A` for line-append, for example). Normal mode in a terminal would allow you to copy previous output. So you jump to the terminal window with normal `C-W j` for example and then you press `a` to append text to the terminal prompt.

Comment: Yes. I typed into the terminal by using insert mode. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

:) i wanted the same thing i searched online to learn how to write a custom function around buffers, then came with this:

```
function SwitchToTerm()
  let term_bufs = getbufinfo({'buflisted':1})
  let curr_buf = bufnr('%')
  call filter(term_bufs, 'v:val.name =~ "^term"')
  call filter(term_bufs, 'v:val.bufnr != ' . curr_buf)
  call map(term_bufs, { _, e -> ({"nr": e.bufnr, "lu": e.lastused}) })
  if bufname('%') =~ "^term"
    call sort(term_bufs, { b1, b2 -> b1.lu - b2.lu })
  else
    call sort(term_bufs, { b1, b2 -> b2.lu - b1.lu })
  endif
  exec "b " . term_bufs[0].nr
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> <Leader>t :call SwitchToTerm()<cr>
```

in my `~/.vimrc` and using Neovim but not sure if that matters. It is supposed to go to the most recently used buffer, then continuously cycle through terminal buffers if already on at a terminal. I switch to BufExplorer a lot to visit another file, and the last terminal becomes iffy there... but switching buffers directly from the command line works fine.